# How does the skill Laser Sight work?

Tags: borderlands-2

Axton's skill "Laser Sight", within the Guerilla Tree, states that it increases the accuracy of shots fired by the Sabre turret.

What exactly is this accuracy? Is it how fast it can swivel to enemies?  Is it how clustered shots are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laser Sight skill improves **accuracy** of Sabre Turret's shots - how clustered the shots are. The Sabre still rotates pretty slow.

As the turret is more useful as a damage sponge than as a damage dealer (in late game), it is generally deployed at enemies' feet, so the accuracy boost is unnecessary. But the skill also grants the turret a visible laser beam, so one skill point would give you a nice indication of what the turret is thinking :)

*I've tried to take screenshots of actual spread, but haven't thought of a place to stage an experiment. Shooting range is small, and the turret is already pretty accurate to nail most targets it bothers to acquire. Anyone can think of a good place, let me know.*